# What is the closest in AWS to Azure Scheduler jobs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-scheduler

I would like to configure recurrent calls (e.g. every minute) to a HTTP/HTTPS endpoint in AWS. What is the easiest way of accomplishing this?
In Azure I would configure a Azure Schedule job for this. Is it anything like that in AWS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Azure Schedule equivalent in AWS. But you can achieve your use case using AWS Lambda. Please check this AWS Guide for doing the same.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html